# Evaluating context of factory for use as within an attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm trying to DRY up a user factory that defines a couple sub classes:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do

    transient do
      kind 'user'
    end

    sequence(:name) { |n| "Factory Girl #{kind} ##{n}" }

    factory :supervisor, class: User do
      kind 'supervisor'
      #...other stuff
    end

    factory :admin, class: User do
      kind 'supervisor'
      #...other stuff
    end

  end
end
```

at the moment I use the transient attribute "kind" to give the user a name that reflects what they are, which comes in handy debugging tests that involve many users

I wondered if there was a way for the name attribute to be set using the name of the factory e.g:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do

    sequence(:name) { |n| "Factory Girl #{__FACTORY_NAME__} ##{n}" }

    factory :supervisor, class: User do
      #...other stuff
    end

    factory :admin, class: User do
      #...other stuff
    end

  end
end
```

I had a dig around but it seems that there is no context available at the point the factory is being evaluated to achieve this. Would that be a correct assumption, or is their some wizardry I can use to achieve this!?